# laravel order model by query

Tags: laravel, model, sql-order-by

I'm working with laravel 5.5.40
I'm trying to use a query to order a model like this:

```
    select * from table1 order by (select nbr from table2 where 
    table2.id=table1.param)
```

so I wanna do this using my model:

```
    $content= Model::where(function($query){
    return $query;
    })
    ->orderBy("????", 'asc')            
    ->paginate(10);
```

where ??? is replaced by a query (select...)
is it possible to do it? and I do need paginate that's important
please help me and thank you

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: my version is 5.5.40. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`orderByRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions):

```php
$content = Model::orderByRaw('(select nbr from table2 where table2.id=table1.param)')            
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: works appearantly, thank you!
however; I was using $content->user->id and now it doesnt work showing Trying to get property of non-object error what do you think about that?

Comment: Please post your query. Does `table2` correspond to `users`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$content = Model::orderBy("????", 'asc')->simplePaginate(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can I replace "???" with (select id from table2...)? that's the problem

Comment: @nacerdjaafri No. You are trying to order the results of the model from another table's id column?